# Splitting Grunt-File into several parts with grunt-load-config: Task not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, configuration, gruntjs, task

I am trying to split my fairly large Grunt File into several smaller parts using load-grunt-config. I have a Gruntfile.js in the root of my project and the child tasks in a directory called grunt.

This is my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
      loadGruntTasks: {
        pattern: '*',
        config: require('./bower.json'),
        scope: 'devDependencies'
      }
    });
};
```

And this for example is my grunt/copy.js file:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  return {
      main: {
        files: [{
          cwd: 'init/php/templates',
          src: '<%= init.php.templates %>',
          dest: 'src/php/templates',
          expand: true
        }],
        options: {
          process: function (content, srcpath) {
            return grunt.template.process(content);
          }
        }
      }
  }
};
```

However no matter what I try (including renaming the copy.js file to grunt-copy.js), Grunt always complains about how it is not able to find my tasks. I am getting this error message:

```
Warning: Task "copy:main" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

I am biting on Granite here. Something must be wrong, however I don't really know what, so any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to get a basic version working? Maybe only have one task with no additional config: `require('load-grunt-config')(grunt);` ? And maybe simplify you're copy task config just to see whether the issue is with your config or the load-grunt-config plugin.

Comment: Silly me, that worked fine. Turns out the problem is the loadGruntTasks part. I use this, to point my install task to the right bower.json, because right now it needs one bower.json in the grunt-folder and one in the root. With the config I solved this problem, but apparently this causes the tasks to crash. Now I need to find a way to just use one bower.json ;)

Comment: Glad you figured at least one part out!

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested. Here is how I solved the Bower.json issue. I am now using the package grunt-bower-task, which is really nice.

Here is my Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    require('load-grunt-config')(grunt);
};
```

The install.js at grunt/bower.js

```
module.exports = {
  install: {
    options: {
      targetDir: "./assets/dev/",
      layout: "byType",
      install: true,
      verbose: false,
      cleanBowerDir: false,
      cleanTargetDir: true,
      bowerOptions: {}
    }
  }
}
```

And my bower.json

```
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "latest",
    "fontawesome": "latest"
  },
  "exportsOverride": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "vendor/js": "**/*.min.js",
      "vendor/css": "**/bootstrap.min.css"
    },
    "jquery": {
      "vendor/js": "**/jQuery.min.js"   
    },
    "fontawesome": {
      "vendor/css": "**/*.min.css",
      "vendor/css/fonts": "**/fontawesome-webfont.*"    
    }
  }
}
```

This automatically sorts all files into vendor/css and vendor/js folders in my dev/assets/ folder and only takes those files from the bower.packages, that I have specified. This really helps to keep the whole setup nice and clean!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the grunt.initConfig() in the Gruntfile.js.
and delivery the data which you want to supply to each task with `require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {data: {pkg: grunt.file.readJSON(./package.json), .....}});`